# Snowflake copy into found character '`' instead of record delimiter '\n'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

File is being exported using below code. When we try to do a copy into in snowflake , we are having issue in loading the file to snowflake. What would be the delimiter here that can be used in file_format in snowflake.

```
df_byte = df.to_csv(compression="gzip", 
     header=False,   
            index=False,   
            na_rep='NULL',  
            sep='Ú'    
            ).encode()
```

Below is current file format

```
    CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS TEST
    TYPE=CSV
    FIELD_DELIMITER ='\xC3\x9A',
    RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n',
    NULL_IF = 'NULL',
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE,
    ESCAPE = '\\',
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE,
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
```

> ERROR we encounter: found character '`' instead of record delimiter '\n'Some of the data is enclosed with " as well with`

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using very unique fiels delimiter try running once without     FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'

if still not work try to export data without quetes using below pandas to_csvparameter
, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE